# UITableView will not load images from XML file

Tags: xml, uitableview, uiimage, xcode4.2, cell

My XMLParser is working fine and I'm parsing all the Elements I need without a problem. For some reason, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will not set the cell image to the image at the url.
If I change the `tempUrl` variable to a link with an image, it works fine, it just won't work with the `[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"srcthumb"];` code line.

I've checked the above code line and it outputs a valid URL in the console without any problems.

What am I doing wrong?
Below is my code:

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Header";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];

    //NSString *tempURL = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"srcthumb"];

    NSString *tempURL =[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"srcthumb"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempURL]]];



    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have white-spaces or bad characters in your `tempURL`, in order to help debug this you should really use:

```
 NSLog(@"The URL im asking for is %@",tempURL);
```

This should show if there are any spaces or bad characters.

This happened to me and I had to Strip the Url of all whitespaces and replace them with the (-) symbol.

Instead of: `www.mysite.com/my image.jpg`

It becomes: `www.mysite.com/my-image.jpg`